# Zend_Form_Element_Image is needed here?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element

How can I make `image preview` and `image-loader` (to replace existing image) into the form via only one Zend element. Zend Framework have any solution?

Zend_Form_Element_Image can be helpfull for that, or I need write my self Zend Element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could simply create My_Form_Element_Xhtml. like that you can add anyting as a form element. i use that for output of wysiwyg editor contents between form elements :)